# Subset and Sample Lists and Tables in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery-m

## Background

Consider this trivial dataset:

|  | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | *1001* | A |
| **2** | *1002* | B |
| **3** | *1003* | C |
| **4** | *1004* | D |
| **5** | *1005* | E |

For an R programmer, it is easy to [subset](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting) this arbitrarily by position:

```r
dataset <- tibble::tribble(
    ~x,   ~y,
    1001, "A",
    1002, "B",
    1003, "C",
    1004, "D",
    1005, "E"
)

dataset[c(4, 1, 3), ]
#         ^^^^^^^
#   Indexing starts at 1
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 × 2
>       x y    
>   <dbl> <chr>
> 1  1004 D    
> 2  1001 A    
> 3  1003 C
> ```

**I want to do likewise in PowerQuery:**

```m
let
    dataset = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.FromRecords({
        [x = 1001, y = "A"],
        [x = 1002, y = "B"],
        [x = 1003, y = "C"],
        [x = 1004, y = "D"],
        [x = 1005, y = "E"]
    }), {
        {"x", type number},
        {"y", type text}
    }),
    
    subset = Foo(dataset, {3, 0, 2})
    //                     ^^^^^^^
    //               Indexing starts at 0
in
    subset
```

Unfortunately, PowerQuery can only do this for *contiguous* ranges, via [`Table.Range()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/table-range) and [`Table.RemoveRows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/table-removerows) and so forth.

## Solution

### `List_Subset()`

This subsets a `list` by position, and it is a workhorse.

```m
let List_Subset = (
    list as list,
    indices as list,
    optional default as nullable any
) as list =>
    let
        // Return an empty list if no positions are supplied...
        result = if List.IsEmpty(indices) then
            {}
            
        // ...and otherwise map the positions to their values, which default when out of bounds.
        else
            List.Transform(indices, each try list{_} otherwise default)
    in
        result
in
    List_Subset
```

### `Table_Subset()`

This extends subsetting to the rows of a `table`.

```m
let Table_Subset = (
    table as table,
    indices as list,
    optional default as nullable record
) as table =>
    let
        // Defaults.
        dfl = if default = null then
            []
        else
            default,
        
        // Preserve the names and types of the columns.
        hdr = Table.FirstN(table, 0),
        
        // Return the empty table if no positions are supplied...
        result = if List.IsEmpty(indices) then
            hdr
            
        // ...and otherwise select the records by position, and stack them under the header.
        else
            let
                rcd = List_Subset(Table.ToRecords(table), indices, dfl),
                sub = Table.InsertRows(hdr, 0, rcd)
            in
                sub
    in
        result
in
    Table_Subset
```

### `List_RandomBetween()`

This is to [`List.Random()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/list-random) what [`Number.RandomBetween()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/number-randombetween) is to [`Number.Random()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/number-random), and it is a helper.

```m
let List_RandomBetween = (
    count as number,
    bottom as number,
    top as number,
    optional seed as nullable number
) as list =>
    let
        // Generate randoms within the range [0, 1]...
        rnd = List.Random(count, seed),
        
        // ...then map them to the range [bottom, top].
        result = List.Transform(rnd, each _ * (top - bottom) + bottom)
    in
        result
in
    List_RandomBetween
```

### `List_RandomInt()`

This generates a `list` of integers between `bottom` and `top`, with or without repetition, and it is a helper.

```m
let List_RandomInt = (
    count as number,
    bottom as number,
    top as number,
    optional repeat as nullable logical,
    optional seed as nullable number
) as list =>
    let
        // Constants.
        INT_COL = "Integer",
        RNK_COL = "Rank",
        
        // Defaults.
        rep = if repeat = null then
            false
        else
            repeat,
        
        // Truncate the count to an integer.
        cnt = Number.RoundDown(count, 0),
        btm = Number.RoundDown(bottom, 0),
        tp = Number.RoundDown(top, 0),
        n = tp - btm + 1,
        
        // Return an empty list for a nonpositive count...
        result = if cnt <= 0 then
            {}
            
        // ...or a list of blanks for invalid bounds...
        else if btm > tp then
            let
                // Without repetition the length is restricted.
                lng = if rep then
                    cnt
                else
                    List.Min({cnt, n}),
                blnk = List.Repeat({null}, lng)
            in
                blnk
            
        // ...and otherwise sample the integers:
        else
            // Sample with repetition by truncating random decimals into integers...
            if rep then
                let
                    rnd = List_RandomBetween(cnt, btm, tp + 1, seed),
                    int = List.Transform(rnd, each Number.RoundDown(_, 0))
                in
                    int
                
            // ...or without repetition by taking the top integers of random rank.
            else
                let
                    rnk = List.Random(n, seed),
                    int = List.Numbers(btm, n, 1),
                    tbl = Table.FromColumns({int, rnk}, {INT_COL, RNK_COL}),
                    srt = Table.Sort(tbl, {RNK_COL, Order.Ascending}),
                    col = Table.Column(srt, INT_COL),
                    top = List.FirstN(col, cnt)
                in
                    top
    in
        result
in
    List_RandomInt
```

### `List_Sample()`

This samples values from a `list`, with or without repetition, and it is a workhorse.

```m
let List_Sample = (
    list as list,
    count as number,
    optional repeat as nullable logical,
    optional order as nullable logical,
    optional seed as nullable number
) as list =>
    let
        // Defaults.
        ord = if order = null then
            true
        else
            order,
        
        // Truncate the count to an integer.
        cnt = Number.RoundDown(count, 0),
        
        // Return an empty list for an empty input or nonpositive count...
        result = if List.IsEmpty(list) or cnt <= 0 then
            {}
            
        // ...and otherwise sample the values:
        else
            let
                // Record the length of the list...
                lng = List.Count(list),
                
                // ...and sample its positions.
                pos = List_RandomInt(cnt, 0, lng - 1, repeat, seed),
                
                // Optionally restore the positions to their original order...
                srt = if ord then
                    List.Sort(pos)
                else
                    pos,
                
                // ...before extracting their values.
                smp = List_Subset(list, srt)
            in
                smp
    in
        result
in
    List_Sample
```

### `Table_Sample()`

This extends sampling to the rows of a `table`.

```m
let Table_Sample = (
    table as table,
    count as number,
    optional repeat as nullable logical,
    optional order as nullable logical,
    optional seed as nullable number
) as table =>
    let
        // Randomly sample the row positions...
        lng = Table.RowCount(table),
        idx = List.Numbers(0, lng, 1),
        rnd = List_Sample(idx, count, repeat, order, seed),
        
        // ...and subset the table by those positions.
        result = Table_Subset(table, rnd)
    in
        result
in
    Table_Sample
```

## Example

When applied to the original example, `List_Subset()` works as intended:

```m
let
    dataset = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.FromRecords({
        [x = 1001, y = "A"],
        [x = 1002, y = "B"],
        [x = 1003, y = "C"],
        [x = 1004, y = "D"],
        [x = 1005, y = "E"]
    }), {
        {"x", type number},
        {"y", type text}
    }),
    
    subset = Table_Subset(dataset, {3, 0, 2})
    //                              ^^^^^^^
    //                        Indexing starts at 0
in
    subset
```

> |  | x | y |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | **1** | *1004* | D |
> | **2** | *1001* | A |
> | **3** | *1003* | C |

## Features

Future features might include

- Letting `Table_Subset()` extract data by row and column simultaneously, where one may specify columns by name or by position: `Table_Subset(dataset, {3, 0, 2}, {"x", 1})`.  This reflects the simultaneous subsetting permitted in R.
- Adding a `skip` argument to `*_Subset()`, which simply omits the results from `indices` that are out of bounds.
- Extending `*_Subset()` to `records` and other data structures.
- Implementing custom `error`s that detail any misuse: indices out of bounds, nonexistent records, contradictory bounds (`bottom` and `top`), and so forth.